# Why does this program with fork print twice?

Tags: c, fork

According to my understanding of `fork()`, this should print "Hello, World!" once, since there is only one process before `fork` is called. However, it prints twice. Curiously, if I add a `\n` to the string or use `puts()` instead of `printf()`, it only prints once.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!");
    fork();
}
```

Comment: Brian, please use search before asking. Many questions already have an answer.

Comment: @2501 I did. I probably didn't use the right terms. I also looked at the top suggestions for things that might answer my question when I was typing the question.

Comment: Try using a third-party search engine, and narrow the search on this site.

Comment: @2501 That's what I used. I think I didn't include `printf` as a term because I didn't realize this was a `printf` problem; I assumed everything before `fork` was being run twice.

Comment: I think this is a much better (clearer) question than the linked duplicates, and would make a good canonical version for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buffering.

Since standard output on your system is buffered by default, it doesn't print immediately. The buffer will however be flushed before the process is exited.

Since `fork` copies the parents entire memory space, file descriptor state, etc, it will also copy the buffered data that needs to be printed.

As such, unless you explicitly flush the standard output buffer before forking (by appending `\n` to the output or calling `fflush(stdout);`), both processes will have buffered output to print.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It helps when that technology has annoying gotchas like this... I just spent well over an hour trying to find the issue in my code before I narrowed it down to this.

Comment: actually it's a duplicate. Damn. Too bad :)

Comment: Where is it specified that "*standard output is buffered by default*"?  AIUI, the initial buffering mode is entirely up to the implementation, and the most common choice is that *[`stdin` and `stdout` are line-buffered **when associated with a terminal**, and fully-buffered otherwise](/a/3746795)*.  Because of this, I advise `fflush()` over `\n`.

Comment: @TobySpeight - If my statement implies I was referring to any particular standard, I wasn't (although I'm not sure how to correct it so it's clearer). It was merely an explanation of the observable behavior of this program.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation I can provide:

`printf("Hello, World!");` doesn't print at once because output is not flushed to `stdout`.

when `fork()` copies process memory, it copies internal buffers, and when both processes terminate, both processes flush their buffers and the text is outputted twice.

Answer (score 2):

Output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes it output) is by default *line buffered*. That means its buffer will be be flushed (and actually written to the output) when you print a newline (or the buffer gets full).

If you don't print a newline, then the buffered output will be duplicated by the child process, and both the parent and child process will each flush its own buffer when the processes ends, leading to two outputs being printed.

Comment: As I noted in a comment to StoryTeller's answer, `stdout` *may* be initially line-buffered, but it's up to the implementation.  All you can say in this situation is that the output was buffered in that particular run of the program.  The general advice (to use `fflush()` if you don't want both parent and child to write the buffered output) still stands, of course.